In what episode did Jillian give birth?
In Ryan's Hope (1975-1989), which episode did Jillian give birth? I remembered that she gave birth with the help of Seneca but I don't remember what episode or date it was aired on. Does anyone know? If you can only remember the year it was shown, I do not mind.

According to this site

Edmund Strong Coleridge Beaulac (played by Buddy Strong)
Edmund was born prematurely in March 1977, only a couple of months before Ryan Fenelli. He is the son of Jillian Coleridge and Frank Ryan, although it was believed that he was Seneca Beaulac's son for his first year or more of life.

IMDB indicates that the first episode for Strong was S1.E452
